# tweeting from node.js "Timestamp out of bounds"

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I've been trying to work with twitter streaming api with node.js and I tried to make a simple test program that just logs tweets.

```js
console.log("start");

var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '****',
  consumer_secret: '****',
  access_token_key: '****',
  access_token_secret: '****'
});

console.log("middle");

client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: "coffee"}, function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
            console.log(tweet);
            console.log("this won't show up.");
        });
  console.log("this will.");
});

console.log("end");
```

when I run it with "node twitter.js" all that logs is start,middle,this will,end. Why is the client not streaming in any data?

Comment: You should: a) console.log(tweet.text) and b) umplement stream.on('error' to see if something is happening there. My guess is an auth error. 'This Will' and 'end' appear due to the asynchronous nature of javascript

Comment: Listen to `error` event, it might give you some clue.